# Angular - toggling state from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a component for my site's menu. I has a method that toggles state from `true` to `false` and another one that listens for click or keypress and - if the user clicks on anywhere on the page *except* the menu, it should hide.

My code looks like this:

```
import app from '../../bootstrap.js';
import template from './siteMenu.html';

class siteMenuController {
  constructor($element) {
    this.activeMenuClass = `${this.className}--active`;
    this.el = $element;
    this.state = false;

    this.listeners();
  }

  activateMenu(close = false) {
    if (close) {
      this.state = false;
    } else {
      this.state = !this.state;
    }
  }

  catchEvent(e) {
    if ((e.type === 'keydown' && e.keyCode === 27) || (e.type === 'click' && e.path.indexOf(this.el[0]) === -1)) {
      this.activateMenu(true);
    }
  }

  listeners() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => { this.catchEvent(e) });
    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => { this.catchEvent(e) });
  }

  $onDestroy() {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', (e) => { this.catchEvent(e) });
    document.removeEventListener('click', (e) => { this.catchEvent(e) });
  }
}
siteMenuController.$inject = ['$element'];

app.component('siteMenu', {
  controller: siteMenuController,
  bindings: {
    items: '<',
    className: '@'
  },
  template,
  transclude: true
});
```

And the template:

```
<nav class="{{ $ctrl.className }}" ng-class="$ctrl.state ? $ctrl.activeMenuClass : null">
  <button class="{{ $ctrl.className }}__trigger" ng-click="$ctrl.state = true">
    <span class="{{ $ctrl.className }}__trigger-line"></span>
    <span class="{{ $ctrl.className }}__trigger-line"></span>
    <span class="{{ $ctrl.className }}__trigger-line"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="{{ $ctrl.className }}__wrapper">
    <li class="{{ $ctrl.className }}__item" ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">
      <a class="{{ $ctrl.className }}__link" href="#{{ item.id }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

My problem is - clicking the trigger works great, clicking on anything else - for closing the menu - doesn't (but `this.state` changes, I traced it in the console).

What can I do?

Comment: you should use event.target for this kind of behaviour

Comment: I don't think this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `addEventListener` you must manually run `$scope.$apply()`, because it doesn't trigger a `$digest` loop.